# Maven Build error when using jaxb2-maven-plugin in contract first SOAP ws

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, jaxb

I'm trying to make my first soap ws using [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-soap-web-service),the xsd file is correct and in the right directory, and the pom is straight up copy-pasted and looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-soap-ws</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-soap-ws</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The problem is the xjc execution. as soon as  copy the plugin in the pom, [this message pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RWxc.png)

```
An internal error occurred during: "Building".
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Then asks me to update the project, which I do, but [the message pops up again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRQ75.png) even though the error disappears from the problems list.

> An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Then, since there is no error apparently, I try to run a `mvn clean install` only to get this error (sorry is awfully long).

```
[[1;34mINFO[m] Scanning for projects...
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------< [0;36mcom.example:spring-boot-soap-ws[0;1m >-------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1mBuilding spring-boot-soap-ws 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-clean-plugin:3.2.0:clean[m [1m(default-clean)[m @ [36mspring-boot-soap-ws[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Deleting C:\Users\Román\eclipse-workspace\spring-boot-soap-ws\target
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mjaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc[m [1m(xjc)[m @ [36mspring-boot-soap-ws[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Generating source...
[[1;34mINFO[m] Analizando un esquema...
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Total time:  1.467 s
[[1;34mINFO[m] Finished at: 2022-10-07T12:26:30+02:00
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/
constituent[1]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/aether-connector-okhttp-0.17.8.jar
constituent[2]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/commons-cli-1.4.jar
constituent[3]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/commons-io-2.6.jar
constituent[4]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
constituent[5]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/guice-4.2.2-no_aop.jar
constituent[6]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/jansi-2.4.0.jar
constituent[7]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
constituent[8]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-artifact-3.8.6.jar
constituent[9]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-builder-support-3.8.6.jar
constituent[10]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-compat-3.8.6.jar
constituent[11]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-core-3.8.6.jar
constituent[12]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-embedder-3.8.6.jar
constituent[13]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-model-3.8.6.jar
constituent[14]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-model-builder-3.8.6.jar
constituent[15]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-plugin-api-3.8.6.jar
constituent[16]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-repository-metadata-3.8.6.jar
constituent[17]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-resolver-api-1.6.3.jar
constituent[18]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.6.3.jar
constituent[19]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-resolver-impl-1.6.3.jar
constituent[20]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-resolver-provider-3.8.6.jar
constituent[21]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-resolver-spi-1.6.3.jar
constituent[22]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-resolver-transport-wagon-1.6.3.jar
constituent[23]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-resolver-util-1.6.3.jar
constituent[24]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-settings-3.8.6.jar
constituent[25]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-settings-builder-3.8.6.jar
constituent[26]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-shared-utils-3.3.4.jar
constituent[27]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/okhttp-3.14.1.jar
constituent[28]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/okio-1.17.3.jar
constituent[29]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.5.jar
constituent[30]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.5.jar
constituent[31]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/plexus-cipher-2.0.jar
constituent[32]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/plexus-component-annotations-2.1.0.jar
constituent[33]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/plexus-interpolation-1.26.jar
constituent[34]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/plexus-sec-dispatcher-2.0.jar
constituent[35]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/plexus-utils-3.3.1.jar
constituent[36]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/wagon-file-3.5.1.jar
constituent[37]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/wagon-provider-api-3.5.1.jar
constituent[38]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_3.8.601.20220820-1147/jars/maven-slf4j-provider-3.8.6.jar
constituent[39]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/7/0/.cp/
constituent[40]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/429/0/.cp/
constituent[41]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/17/0/.cp/
constituent[42]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/3/0/.cp/
constituent[43]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/4/0/.cp/
constituent[44]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/94/0/.cp/
constituent[45]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/237/0/.cp/
constituent[46]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/364/0/.cp/
constituent[47]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/262/0/.cp/
constituent[48]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/156/0/.cp/
constituent[49]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/88/0/.cp/
constituent[50]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/200/0/.cp/
constituent[51]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/199/0/.cp/
constituent[52]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/78/0/.cp/
constituent[53]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/154/0/.cp/
constituent[54]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/339/0/.cp/
constituent[55]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/77/0/.cp/
constituent[56]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/155/0/.cp/
constituent[57]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/361/0/.cp/
constituent[58]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/240/0/.cp/
constituent[59]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/384/0/.cp/
constituent[60]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/83/0/.cp/
constituent[61]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/95/0/.cp/
constituent[62]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/96/0/.cp/
constituent[63]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/261/0/.cp/
constituent[64]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/92/0/.cp/
constituent[65]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/273/0/.cp/
constituent[66]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common_3.2.1.20220620-0741/
constituent[67]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common_3.2.1.20220620-0741/jars/archetype-catalog-3.2.1.jar
constituent[68]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common_3.2.1.20220620-0741/jars/archetype-common-3.2.1.jar
constituent[69]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common_3.2.1.20220620-0741/jars/archetype-descriptor-3.2.1.jar
constituent[70]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common_3.2.1.20220620-0741/jars/jdom2-2.0.6.jar
constituent[71]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common_3.2.1.20220620-0741/jars/maven-artifact-transfer-0.13.1.jar
constituent[72]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/369/0/.cp/
constituent[73]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/86/0/.cp/
constituent[74]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/367/0/.cp/
constituent[75]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/85/0/.cp/
constituent[76]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/75/0/.cp/
constituent[77]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/254/0/.cp/
constituent[78]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/417/0/.cp/
constituent[79]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/415/0/.cp/
constituent[80]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/383/0/.cp/
constituent[81]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/344/0/.cp/
constituent[82]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/8/0/.cp/
constituent[83]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/280/0/.cp/
constituent[84]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/37/0/.cp/
constituent[85]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/64/0/.cp/
constituent[86]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/333/0/.cp/
constituent[87]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/141/0/.cp/
constituent[88]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/144/0/.cp/
constituent[89]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/145/0/.cp/
constituent[90]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/143/0/.cp/
constituent[91]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/395/0/.cp/
constituent[92]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/392/0/.cp/
constituent[93]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/396/0/.cp/
constituent[94]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/397/0/.cp/
constituent[95]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/205/0/.cp/
constituent[96]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/379/0/.cp/
constituent[97]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/177/0/.cp/
constituent[98]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/181/0/.cp/
constituent[99]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/105/0/.cp/
constituent[100]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/100/0/.cp/
constituent[101]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/119/0/.cp/
constituent[102]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/99/0/.cp/
constituent[103]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/113/0/.cp/
constituent[104]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/101/0/.cp/
constituent[105]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/103/0/.cp/
constituent[106]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/375/0/.cp/
constituent[107]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/15/0/.cp/
constituent[108]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/108/0/.cp/
constituent[109]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/109/0/.cp/
constituent[110]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/238/0/.cp/
constituent[111]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/82/0/.cp/
constituent[112]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/81/0/.cp/
constituent[113]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/122/0/.cp/
constituent[114]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/111/0/.cp/
constituent[115]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/114/0/.cp/
constituent[116]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/110/0/.cp/
constituent[117]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/107/0/.cp/
constituent[118]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/123/0/.cp/
constituent[119]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/120/0/.cp/
constituent[120]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/116/0/.cp/
constituent[121]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/121/0/.cp/
constituent[122]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/139/0/.cp/
constituent[123]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/412/0/.cp/
constituent[124]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/413/0/.cp/
constituent[125]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/414/0/.cp/
constituent[126]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/416/0/.cp/
constituent[127]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/418/0/.cp/
constituent[128]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/419/0/.cp/
constituent[129]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/420/0/.cp/
constituent[130]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/421/0/.cp/
constituent[131]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/13/0/.cp/
constituent[132]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/142/0/.cp/
constituent[133]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/394/0/.cp/
constituent[134]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/391/0/.cp/
constituent[135]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/497/0/.cp/
constituent[136]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/58/0/.cp/
constituent[137]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/62/2/.cp/
constituent[138]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/169/0/.cp/
constituent[139]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/171/0/.cp/
constituent[140]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/182/0/.cp/
constituent[141]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/187/0/.cp/
constituent[142]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/210/0/.cp/
constituent[143]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/106/0/.cp/
constituent[144]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/40/0/.cp/
constituent[145]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/102/0/.cp/
constituent[146]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/431/0/.cp/
constituent[147]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/34/0/.cp/
constituent[148]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/79/0/.cp/
constituent[149]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/112/0/.cp/
constituent[150]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/118/0/.cp/
constituent[151]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/386/0/.cp/
constituent[152]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/104/0/.cp/
constituent[153]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/425/0/.cp/
constituent[154]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/393/0/.cp/
constituent[155]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/495/0/.cp/
constituent[156]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/59/0/.cp/
constituent[157]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/63/2/.cp/
constituent[158]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/430/2/.cp/
constituent[159]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/180/0/.cp/
constituent[160]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/201/0/.cp/
constituent[161]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/36/0/.cp/
constituent[162]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/33/0/.cp/
constituent[163]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/35/0/.cp/
constituent[164]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/60/0/.cp/
constituent[165]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/434/0/.cp/
constituent[166]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/11/0/.cp/
constituent[167]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/12/0/.cp/
constituent[168]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/422/0/.cp/
constituent[169]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/334/0/.cp/
constituent[170]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/39/0/.cp/
constituent[171]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/41/0/.cp/
constituent[172]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/433/0/.cp/
constituent[173]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/423/0/.cp/
constituent[174]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/424/0/.cp/
constituent[175]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/426/0/.cp/
constituent[176]: file:/C:/Users/Román/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/432/0/.cp/
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:113)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.<init>(BGMBuilder.java:147)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.build(BGMBuilder.java:117)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.annotateXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:425)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:174)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:119)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:333)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractXjcMojo.execute(AbstractXjcMojo.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:196)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:102)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:113)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BindingComponent.getClassSelector(BindingComponent.java:65)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.ColorBinder.<init>(ColorBinder.java:62)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BindGreen.<init>(BindGreen.java:63)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:102)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/MimeTypeParseException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3373)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3578)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2754)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.Ring.get(Ring.java:100)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.DefaultClassBinder.<init>(DefaultClassBinder.java:98)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.ClassSelector.<init>(ClassSelector.java:214)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 53 more
```

Iv'e seen that `xjc` is not supported from java 9 up,and people were having problems with it, but neither of them were getting the same error. Also, `xjc` should work in Java 8 so I found a [tutorial in youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ceSqN3CWd14&t=137s) which does exactly this but he doesn't get this error. I have eclipse set up to the same Java versions and running environment as the video and the guide, but nothing seems to work.

At this point I'm pretty hopeless, and probably the error will be something I'm totally missing, but I would appreciate greatly if someone pointed me in the right direction